# Using j2objc throws errors "Class cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, objective-c, j2objc

I am using j2objc.

I have 2 classes:

- LabelPosition.java
- Event.java

In Event I have references to LabelPostion

I could translate the standalone Class Labelposition without problems.
Packagestructure and the File .h & -m are created.

Now I try to translate the Event.java, which has references to LabelPosition as follow:

```
./j2objc --verbose -d objective-c -sourcepath . Event.java
```

I get errors:

```
error: Event.java:79: LabelPosition cannot be resolved to a type
error: Event.java:79: LabelPosition cannot be resolved to a type
error: Event.java:284: LabelPosition cannot be resolved to a type
error: Event.java:285: LabelPosition cannot be resolved to a type
error: Event.java:287: LabelPosition cannot be resolved to a type
error: Event.java:288: LabelPosition cannot be resolved to a type
```

Following screens shows my Folderstructur:
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode can't handle headers in sub-directories -- everything has to be in the same directory. This is easy to fix: add the --no-package-directories flag and rebuild everything.

Comment: i just added the --no-package-directories to my existing command, but I got the same error again. You mentoined it has to be all in the same folder. That do you mean with all regarding my folderstructur in the screenshot ? -> "Events.ava" and "LabelPositon.java" are in the same folder as the command j2objc. Anything else to do ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were building in Xcode. Does "javac -d objective-c -sourcepath . Event.java" succeed? j2objc's front-end is a Java compiler, and it needs the same paths that javac does. My guess is that one or both of these sources have a package statement, and so should be in sub-directories that match that statement. For example, if LabelPosition has "package foo.bar;" then the source needs to be in foo/bar/LabelPosition.java. In any event, the general trick is to first define a javac command that works, then change "javac" to "j2objc".